What part of speech is "study" in this sentence and how would it relate to either the direct object or subject?
The sentence is: "The teacher helped me study."
I'd like to know what part of speech "study" is from a syntax point of view.
As far as I know, it is a verb that is being done by the direct object, but I may be wrong about that.

Closely related: What is the difference between a bare infinitive and an infinitive? The answer there should answer your question.

What's your reason for not being sure it's a verb?

Rather than being unsure it's a verb, I'm unsure that the direct object is the one doing the verb.

Of course it is. 'You' are the one studying, with the teacher's help.

See also this and this.
